# PHP Google oauth2

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

I am using Xampp and I wanted to integrate sending Gmail over PHP. I see that everybody recommend PHP Mailer so I download Composer and install phpmailer `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`. After that i install google oauth2: `composer require league/oauth2-google`.

I look at [this](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google)  link to use : Authorization Code Flow.

Google API is all set up (i got  APP-id and Secret)

when i run `get_oauth_token.php` i get error:
`Uncaught Error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\telesales\gentelella-master\production\PHPMailer\get_oauth_token.php`

my composer.json is this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "league/oauth2-client": "^2.3",
        "stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft": "^2.2"
    }
}
```

Sorry, but I am new at this and cannot find why .php page wont find Class.

Here is get_oauth_token.php

```
<?php
$provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google([
    'clientId'     => '{google-app-id}',
    'clientSecret' => '{google-app-secret}',
    'redirectUri'  => 'https://example.com/callback-url',
    'hostedDomain' => 'example.com', // optional; used to restrict access to users on your G Suite/Google Apps for Business accounts
]);

if (!empty($_GET['error'])) {

    // Got an error, probably user denied access
    exit('Got error: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['error'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

} elseif (empty($_GET['code'])) {

    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;

} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

    // State is invalid, possible CSRF attack in progress
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');

} else {

    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ]);

    // Optional: Now you have a token you can look up a users profile data
    try {

        // We got an access token, let's now get the owner details
        $ownerDetails = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

        // Use these details to create a new profile
        printf('Hello %s!', $ownerDetails->getFirstName());

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // Failed to get user details
        exit('Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage());

    }

    // Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
    echo $token->getToken();

    // Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo $token->getRefreshToken();

    // Number of seconds until the access token will expire, and need refreshing
    echo $token->getExpires();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why does your composer.json contain `stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft`? That's the package needed for connecting to MS servers, not google. That will be why your Google oauth class isn't being found.

Comment: i install MS package also (maybe for furder usage) but did know that would be the problem. I install Google and Microsoft package. When i remove line: `"stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft": "^2.2"` i got the same Error.

Comment: You need to include autoloader at the beginning of this file: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: i add `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at begining of `get_oauth_token.php` but still same error. Do i need to restart or reinstall something after altering code in files?

Comment: Also why i have `composer.json` in my root folder (root of PHPmailer) and composer.json in `\vendor\league\oauth2-client`

Comment: Look at the composer file you posted - despite you saying that you ran `composer require league/oauth2-google`, that package is not in your composer file, so it's probably just missing and you need to install it again. `oauth2-client` is a generic package which the provider-specific versions build on, it's not the same thing as `oauth2-google`.

Comment: Thanks, i did not realize that `oauth2-client` is different from `oauth2-google`. I install that and use this script [link](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google). Now script get me to google login, but after login i get message 'Invalid state'

Comment: Why would you need a different library for Google vs Microsoft when they're both oauth2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just making the same but without composer. First it's not working with some errors. While I am searching the solution for troubleshooting, and try to edit some lines, finally it's working now. with this result :

```
            2018-05-27 02:41:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
2018-05-27 02:41:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mybasic.local
2018-05-27 02:41:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.213.130.29]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-05-27 02:41:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-05-27 02:41:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-05-27 02:41:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO myweb.local
2018-05-27 02:41:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.213.130.29]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-05-27 02:41:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-05-27 02:41:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-05-27 02:41:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-05-27 02:41:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-05-27 02:41:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<your_email@gmail.com>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<your_email_or_other@gmail.com>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2018-05-27 02:41:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Go ahead q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sun, 27 May 2018 04:41:44 +0200
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Test System <your_email@gmail.com>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Test System <your_email@gmail.com>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <ECAniOwmuQcv1zYojWJ3VxZx8xCqVgayTymBYoKlKk@mybasic.local>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_ECAniOwmuQcv1zYojWJ3VxZx8xCqVgayTymBYoKlKk"
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_ECAniOwmuQcv1zYojWJ3VxZx8xCqVgayTymBYoKlKk
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_ECAniOwmuQcv1zYojWJ3VxZx8xCqVgayTymBYoKlKk
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_ECAniOwmuQcv1zYojWJ3VxZx8xCqVgayTymBYoKlKk--
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2018-05-27 02:41:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2018-05-27 02:41:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1527388939 q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
2018-05-27 02:41:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-05-27 02:41:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection q126-v6sm37491953pga.79 - gsmtp
Message has been sent
```

My code :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php'; // make sure the folder is right
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

//Load Composer's autoloader
//require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // if using composer

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->Username = 'your_email@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
     $mail->Password = 'your_email_password';  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

     $mail->setFrom('your_email@gmail.com', 'Test System');
     $mail->addAddress('your_email_or_other@gmail.com', 'Test System');  
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I also disabled/comment all lines related to email on php.ini in the folder xampp/php and reload the xampp.

Get the latest code from : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I use your code but got an error:  `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.` Also when i run `get_oauth_token.php` it get me to Google login and i accept app and the display `Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script`

Comment: Meaning your password was not correct.... OR you must change your google account to Less secure apps. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: yes, I change to Less secure' and it worked. Now another problem is that at my home it is working ok, but in my office won't because of the proxy restrictions. 
Also is it possible that I did not have to enter my email & pass? Many user will use script so they can login with their google account?

Comment: No worry about email password. If someone can hack that code meaning he can hack all your codes / website. Please up vote if my code is helps you.